# Efficiently store picture in Firebase Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

As storing pictures is going to be one of the more expensive features of Firebase my app will be using I want to make sure I'm doing it efficiently.

The steps I'm taking are the following:

1. Resize picture the user wants to upload to have width of 500 points (A point represents a pixel on non-retina screens and two pixels on retina screens)
2. Upload the data for the specified image in PNG format to Firebase storage

Here's my actual code:

```
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(name).png")
if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profImage.resizeImage(targetSize: CGSize(width: 500, height: Int(500*(profImage.size.height/profImage.size.width))))) {
    storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: nil)
}
```

The photos are going to be a little less than the width of an iPhone screen when displayed to the user. Is the way I'm storing them efficient or is there a better way to format them?

**Edit: After a bit more research I've found out that JPGs are more efficient than PNG so I'll be switching to that since transparency isn't important for me. See my answer for example.

Comment: Hi MarksCode. Do edit out your post to remove the solution and post it as an answer (see [Self Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) along with the details of your research on why you ended up with that conclusion. Cheers! :)

Comment: Will do AL! Thanks for always helping people out. As a CS student, you,  firebase employees, and other experienced people mean the world to me.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for helping to the community as well. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the image format from png to jpeg and found it saves a lot of space. Here's a picture of my storage for comparisons:

[image: storage]

My code went from using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with a compression factor of 1. I'm sure if I reduce the compression factor it'll save even more space.